# Why does Django create redundant indexes?

Tags: python, sql, django

The Django model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", symmetrical=False)
```

generates this SQL

```
CREATE TABLE "tweets_userprofile" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "user_id" integer NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"));
CREATE TABLE "tweets_userprofile_followers" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "from_userprofile_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "tweets_userprofile" ("id"), "to_userprofile_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "tweets_userprofile" ("id"));
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "tweets_userprofile_followers_from_userprofile_id_a8c8e3db_uniq" ON "tweets_userprofile_followers" ("from_userprofile_id", "to_userprofile_id");
CREATE INDEX "tweets_userprofile_followers_6c3c534c" ON "tweets_userprofile_followers" ("from_userprofile_id");
CREATE INDEX "tweets_userprofile_followers_257192e2" ON "tweets_userprofile_followers" ("to_userprofile_id");
```

I understand that the unique index is there to prevent duplicates.

Isn't having both an index on `(from_userprofile_id, to_userprofile_id)` and on `(from_userprofile_id)` redundant though?

Besides, doesn't having the `REFERENCES` keyword automatically create indexes since they are foreign keys? When writing a model with a `ForeignKey`, Django doesn't generate any extra `CREATE INDEX` statements besides the `REFERENCES` keyword when creating the table, so why does it do that for `ManyToManyField`?

If the indexes are indeed redundant, does this mean every write triggers extra index table writes, or is the DB clever enough to detect duplicates?